# How to detect that a PC has been idle for 30 seconds using Java?

Tags: java

How to detect that a PC has been idle for 30 seconds using Java?

EDITED

With idle I mean that there are no user activity. The user does nothing in 30 seconds. I wold like to do an apllication like Windows, that detects that the user does nothing and enter in stad-by.

Comment: can you rephrase your question in a more specific way?

Comment: You need to define 'idle' - is it no user input, no disk activity, no processes running, an average CPU load or what?

Comment: What does "idle" even mean? No/little CPU activitiy (what about multiproc systems)? No user input? No network traffic? No harddisk I/O?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Directly from java it is not possible. You'll have to find some native library and create a JNI wrapper for that.

Answer (score 12):

I've come across this excellent example of detecting system wide idle time using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/). [Java Native Access (JNA)](https://github.com/twall/jna/) is a library that provides access to [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/index.html) without the need for you to actually write native code.

[Here's the example](http://ochafik.free.fr/blog/?p=98) that is very close to what you're asking for.

Answer (score 7):

Not possible as requested, but you can create workarounds using the [java.lang.management API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/package-summary.html). A JNI implementation can also be found on [javaworld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2002-11/01-qa-1108-cpu.html).

Answer (score 5):

Not easy to do have a look at OperatingSystemMXBean method getSystemLoadAverage() only available since java 6 you could keep a track of it and if it is the same for a while determine the pc is idle.

This assumes idle in terms of idle CPU

> OperatingSystemMXBean
>   operatingSystemMxBean =
>   ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();

Comment: It always returns -1 on Windows 7. Any hints?

Comment: According to the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html). If the load average is not available, a negative value is returned. You could be out of luck for this method working on Windows 7.